# MVC c# controller return view()

Tags: asp.net-mvc

below is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Models = We.Models;
using We.BAL;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Helpers;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.Security;
using PagedList;
using We.Models.ViewModels;
using We.Models.Interface;
using We.Models.DBData;
using We.Models.Repository;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.Query;
using System.Data.SqlClient;  

namespace We.Controllers
{
    public class ClientEnquiryController : Controller
    {
      private Models.Interface.IPolicyService _repository;  
      private Models.Repository.PolicyServiceRepository clientenqRepository;    

      public ClientEnquiryController()
           : this(new Models.Repository.PolicyServiceRepository())
      { 
      }

      public ClientEnquiryController(Models.Interface.IPolicyService repository)
      {
        _repository = repository;
      }

      public ActionResult MasterView( string PolicyNo, string carrierCode, string sPol, string languageCode)
      {
        carrierCode = "2";
        sPol = "502-0877220";
        languageCode = "eng";
        return View(_repository.policymaster(carrierCode, sPol, languageCode));            
      }
```

From my codeI am do the return like this :

```
return View(_repository.policymaster(carrierCode, sPol, languageCode));
```

how about if i want return the view with more than one statement in same time? for example:

```
_repository.policymaster(carrierCode, sPol, languageCode);
_repository.policyAgent(carrierCode, sPol, languageCode);
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might benefit from modelling the view with the two return objects.  For example,

```
public class MasterViewVM
{
    public PolicyMaster {get; set;}
    public PolicyAgent {get; set;}
}
```

Then you return the view model with the data entities:

```
public ActionResult MasterView(string PolicyNo, 
    string carrierCode, string sPol, string languageCode)
    {
        carrierCode = "2";
        sPol = "502-0877220";
        languageCode = "eng";
        MasterViewVM model = new MasterViewVM
        {
           PolicyMaster =_repository.policymaster(carrierCode, sPol, languageCode),
           PolicyAgent = _repository.policyAgent(carrierCode, sPol, languageCode)
        };
       return View(model);
    }
```

Another possibility is to use a child action.  See

http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx

Comment: for 

    public class MasterViewVM
    {
        public PolicyMaster {get; set;}
        public PolicyAgent {get; set;}
    }


what type I need to use?
I am passing the value to the store procedure parameter.

Comment: @user1705287 - I'm afraid I don't understand your question.  The class is modeling the view and is not really involved in stored procedure parameters.  The answer was meant to illustrate how to pass the two complex objects, PolicyMaster and PolicyAgent, to the view.